# How to convert a text file seperated by a new line to a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, text

How do i convert a text file seperated by a new line to a csv file.

**Text File Sample**

```
/themes/modern/user_style.php?user_colors[bg_color]="</style><script></script>
?<meta http-equiv=set-cookie content="testpokn=7494">
/_37040/
/clr_cream/
reg_req/
trackir3pro-1/
selector_10274/
javascript/orders.html
perlutil/
/carte_ameriques2/
/javascript/count.conf
/glow_chairs/
```

I want to convert this AS is to a csv file. 1 column, multiple rows. Each line of the text file should be a row in the csv file.

**Python**

```
def loadFile(name):

    directory = os.getcwd()
    filepath = directory + "/" + name
    data = open(filepath,'r').readlines()

    result = []
    for d in data:
        d = str(urllib.parse.unquote(d))
        result.append(d)
    return result



def main():

    data = loadFile('code.txt')

    with open('new.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp,)
        a.writerows(data)

main()
```

My problem is that for each char it adds a comma

Comment: And how is that a problem?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  "/_37040/" becomes "/,_,3,7,0,4,0" this is why its a problem. i want 1 column multiple rows.

Comment: If you want only one column, your input file **is** already a single column CSV file...

Answer (score 0):

`writerows` should use a list for list or tuple, like `[('bla', ), ('bla', )]`

```
def main():
    data = loadFile('code.txt')

    with open('new.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp,)
        a.writerows([(r, ) for r in data])
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrong output comes from your usage of `writerows`. It is supposed to receive an iterable (of lines) of iterables (of columns). As you give it a list of strings, it takes each string as an iterable of characters, hence the output.

A simple fix would be that `loadFile` returns a list of 1-tuple of strings:

```
def loadFile(name):

    directory = os.getcwd()
    filepath = directory + "/" + name
    data = open(filepath,'r').readlines()

    result = []
    for d in data:
        d = str(urllib.parse.unquote(d))
        result.append((d,))   # result now contains 1-tuple of strings
    return result
```

But anyway, as you process each line separately, if would be much more memory friendly to have this general program structure:

- open input file and output csv (`with open(...) as ...`)
- loop over input file by lines (`for line in ...:`)

  - compute what the line should become
  - write it to the output file